# Reset network monitor stats in Android Studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio

The Y axis spikes and I only know how to reset it by restarting the IDE. I tried clicking, right-clicking dragging... no luck!

There must be a way in the IDE to reset this back down to the single KB/s range, right?

[image]

Comment: nobody??? sriously guys,, cmeun

Answer (score 0):

The Network Monitor of Android Studio seems to miss this feature. However you can use the `Android Device Monitor` as well to monitor the network traffic and guess what this one actually has a reset button.

In order to use it open `Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor`. Afterwards click on the `Network Statistics` tab and the `Start` Button.
Following a screenshot which shows the feature:

[image: Screenshot of network statistics in Android Device Monitor]